# I don't want to be visible on Steam Friends web pages

Tags: steam

If I become someone's friend on Steam, then I appear on their Friends list, even if I don't have a profile created, or if I do have a profile, I cannot delete it.

There are people I want to be friends with, but I don't want other people seeing that I'm "friends" with them (it's complicated), short of opening another account (and rebuying my games again) is there any way to be "secret friends" with others?

Answer (score 2):

Although there is no way to do this, you can just create a group and invite them in. They will still be able to chat with you if you both are that group's chatroom.

While You can double click on his/her name in the list on the right and chat privately, invite them, join them etc. Be aware that they'll get a message, telling them that you are trying to chat and will ask them if he/she wants that.

Also, you are friends, or you are not. You can't just be secret friends. It is never that complicated. At least you shouldn't let it be this complicated.

Comment: Also, you are friends, or you are not. You can't just be secret friends. It is never that complicated. At least you shouldn't let it be this complicated.

Comment: They can still see who is a member of that group and that he is the administrator of that group, so not really a workaround.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness well, he asked how to not be friends but be able to chat, this is how. He didn't say "we can't be in same group too".

Comment: @ardaozkal - OP doesn't mention chat at all. Besides, there's a lot of things that having friends is nice for, like extra inventory space, seeing who is playing what etc. Also I'd add your first comment into your answer - it's the main point you should be getting across :)

Comment: @Robotnik "extra inventory space" wot? Can you explain that? I guess all the scammers adding me is not a big problem anymore. (also I added)

Comment: @ardaozkal I derped lol - Leveling up your profile gets you more space for adding additional Steam Friends. Nothing to do with the inventory, and completely the wrong way around. Whoops :)

Comment: @Robotnik yeah I know, I have like 500 space. 300 is occupied, they just have me to have someone "with ~600 games and 40+ level" in their friends list, some are torture (begging all the day), some are quiet (adds and never messages), some are good (they become friends), I accept all, just because of the good ones.

Comment: @ardaozkal - I accept most, so I can request trading cards lol. Obvious spam accounts I remove.

Comment: @Robotnik hmm, I guess I'll try that trick and will go up to level 50 2nite.

Answer (score 1):

The only really viable course of action here is to get an alternative Chat Client such as Jabber, ICQ, MSN or the more gaming related Raptr Client and befriend them over those services. All of them have a client. In case of Raptr (aka AMD Gaming Evolved) you can also earn points to buy games with just by playing a game. There are even more offers if you have a AMD Video Card.

Comment: He asked how to be friends with them **on steam**. He'll probably want to play together with them etc.

Comment: @ardaozkal Nevertheless, this is good info to have: the OP might not be the only one helped by this question, and knowing that there are other options out there is always good :)

Comment: @Robotnik yep, I totally forgot about that.